# why sign flip to indicate loss in hyperopt?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, classification, scikit-learn, hyperparameter-tuning

I am using the hyperopt to find best hyperparameters for Random forest.

My objective is to get the parameters which returns the `best f1-score` as my dataset is imbalanced.

So, I defined the below objective function based on a tutorial online

```
space = {
    "n_estimators": hp.choice("n_estimators", [100, 200, 300, 400,500,600]),
    "max_depth": hp.quniform("max_depth", 1, 15,1),
    "criterion": hp.choice("criterion", ["gini", "entropy"]),
    "max_features": hp.quniform("max_features", 1, 14,1)
}

def hyperparameter_tuning(params):
    clf = RandomForestClassifier(**params,n_jobs=-1)
    f1score = cross_val_score(clf, ord_train_t, y_train,scoring="f1").mean()
    return {"loss": -f1score, "status": STATUS_OK}
```

Am I doing this right?

If I remove the `loss` keyword from `return` statement it throws `key error`.

Why is it so? I just wish to name the `key` as `f1score` but it threw error.

Once I changed it back to `loss`, it started working fine.

I get output like below

88%|████████████████████████████████████████▍     | 88/100 [29:42<03:25, 17.14s/tri  best loss: -0.8615863383404218

Does it mean my model returns an f1-score of 86%?

Shouldn't the loss be 100-86 = 14?

btw, why is it that we should `sign-flip` the `f1score` to indicate loss?

Comment: Answered, hope it answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fmin function is the optimization function that iterates on different sets of algorithms and their hyperparameters and then minimizes the objective function. In Hyperopt we try to find the parameters which minimizes the loss. So if you have evaluation metrics that needs maximizing like accuracy, F1 score we change the sign so that minimizing is equal to maximise the evaluation metrics.

So lets say you use f1-score, you need to maximise you pass negation so that minimizing it will maximise it

```
F1 Score = 0.89  Loss = -0.89

F1 Score = 0.91  Loss = -0.91
```

**Negation make sure your hyperparameter which maximises F1 score 0.91 are chosed though Hyperopt minimized it.**

Also, if you have metrics like RMSE, MAE which needs to minimised you don't need to flip it.